# Database design: how to handle roles when some roles overlap?

Tags: database, database-design

There are some situations where one user can have different roles, one common example is the OWNER, DRIVER and CAB.

#### Example

1. There are OWNERS who owns TAXIS. ***(One:owner to Many:taxis)***
2. TAXIS could have one or more allocated drivers and drivers can drive multiple taxis. ***(Many: drivers to Many: taxis)***
3. Sometimes the OWNER can be the same taxi DRIVER in this case the same person share two ROLES. ***(?)***

#### Possible approach

[image: e]

Problem

1. With this approach there is redundancy of data between entities DRIVER and OWNER because it is necessary to know the same data as `names`, `lastnames`, `identification number`, `email`, etc. this situation occurs when OWNER is a different person than the DRIVER. the only additional information for the DRIVER is his `driver_license_number`.
2. How to model the situation where the OWNER is the same DRIVER?

#### Second approach update

[image]

Comment: You need a "parent" entity for owner and driver. Like "person".  But overlap there.  Then have owner and driver tables have FK to person...and put any owner-only .. driver-only info in that table.           PS   "owner_names" and "owner_last_names) is a very confusing attribute number.   if you go traditional, it would be "firstname", middlename and "lastname".    but keep in mind, some people have have more than 3 "pieces" to their names.  I hope you are NOT storing more than one owner's name in that column.

Comment: Why not have a single table that identifies all `people` a table for all `cabs` and a cross reference table that contains `person_id`, `cab_id`, and two bit fields that indicate `driver` and `owner`. This would allow for a single person to own and/or drive any of the cabs.

Comment: @granadaCoder Can you check my second approach upload?, assuming I catch what you explained in your answer. But what about the `ManyToMany` relationship between CAR and DRIVER?

Comment: @gmiley When you talk about `two bit fields that indicate driver and owner`, this fields should go in `reference table`? should be booleans? or what do you mean with this approach?

Comment: Create a cross-reference table the links the people ro the cars, a many to many, and keep the relation type bit fields in that. It will allow you to have any combination of owner and driver for any of the cars. 1 or more owners or 1 or more drivers and any combination of them.

Comment: @gmiley what types of fields should be OWNER and DRIVER in the bridge table? booleans? other thing, I dont need to track the owners for one car. I mean, I just need to know the current owner, not the owners that might own a car over time. then this approach can fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an entity `Person` with a single subtype (for now): `Driver`.  This will avoid the duplication of data issue and allow you to store the relevant information (license #) with the relevant entity.

We do not need an owner subtype as there would be no additional information required (at this point) to distinguish a `Person` from an "Owner".  If this changes, then there would be two non-exclusive subtypes for `Person` and the `Owner` subtype would have the relation to `Vehicle`.

[image]

Comment: For me, it's the best approach to solving mt question. Can you extend your explanation a little better about the driver/car relationship? `VehicleDriver` its a join or bridge table, then I assume the car and driver IDs must be on it, let me know if I'm right. Finally, should the cardinality between person and owner/driver be `OneToOne` or `OneToMany`?

Comment: `VehicleDriver` would be referred to as a junction or bridge table by some, and that is what is currently modeled: `Vehicle driven by zero to many Drivers`, `Driver drives zero to many vehicles`.  The cardinality for person to owner/driver is `Person is Owner` and/or `Person is Driver`, which is a `one to zero to one` relationship with each subtype.

Comment: Just noticed owner refers to the owner of the vehicle - in this case no `Owner` subtype is required, let me update the data model to clarify this.

Comment: @CristianCamiloFlórez Also, from lengthy personal experience, it is highly recommended to use the 17 digit vehicle identification number as the primary key.  If you must use an surrogate ("Id") make sure the `VIN` is an alternate key.  You would probably also want an alternate key on `PlateNumber` to avoid data quality issues in the future.

Comment: With the new model you used I have some questions. In the table `Vehicle` you put `OwnerId` you refer to `PersonId`? and what about `Person` / `Driver` relationship, `Driver` must have a `person` field targeting `Person` table in a one-on-one relationship? I updated my second approach in my question to see that I catch all your points.

Comment: `OwnerId` is the `PersonId` inherited through the relation `Person Owns Vehicle` but the name is changed to nature of the relationship.  You could use `OwnerPersonId` or something similar as well.  A `Driver` is a `Person`, but the key is renamed to distinguish a `Driver` from a `Person` who is not a driver.

Answer (score 0):

You can have another entity (person) that both owner and driver are part of. A person can have more than just one role (owner/ driver). Then you have one data entity per person.

Comment: What do you mean with card? assuming you mean car, what about the situation where a DRIVER can drive many CAR?

Comment: I meant card as a new data entity - person.

Comment: When you say that PERSON and OWNER are part of person, are they as attributes? what kind of attributes, booleans? or are they separate tables that relate to person? What about the relation between CAR and PERSON? I think that could be a good aproach but i dont have enough information.

Comment: It's basically just creating a super-entity that will have the attributes of both the owner and the driver like name (first and last), IDs, and stuff like that. Very similar to your edit.